# how should I execute this command properly in C

Tags: c

I am currently using popen to execute a command via C, but it is not coming out properly so I was just wondering If I was doing anything wrong?

the original command (previously called via a bash script but I am now making a C program to call it instead) is

```
   /home/minecraft/remoteclient01a.py "sendmsgtogroup staff §f(§bSTAFF§f) * $colourcode$MCEXEC_PLAYERNAME§f $MCEXEC_ARGS"
```

and the way I am trying to execute it in C is

```
   snprintf(command, 10000, "/home/minecraft/remoteclient01a.py 'sendmsgtogroup staff  §f(§bSTAFF§f) * %s§f %s'", pname, parg);
   popen(command, "w");
```

but for someone reason the last variable (parg) does not seem to be included when the command is executed, If someone could let me know if I am messing something up i would really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: You need to give more code for context.  Preferably an example that is self-contained and others can compile.  ( See: http://sscce.org/ )  However as a test, have you tried--for instance--swapping `pname` and `parg` to see what happens?

Comment: what you see after execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh wait, it appears that an irc listener was not configured to pick it up properly which put up the illusion that nothing was being passed through, is actually working fine though, thanks for your input though! "is embarrassed"